# How to order subset data.frame based on other vector

Tags: r

Using R, my situation is:

I have a dataframe with 10 columns from v1 to v10 and some instances where v10 is the target value of a regression. I have also another dataframe with columsn v1 to v9 but in different order.

```
df = v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
df2 = v8 v3 v6 v4 v2 v7 v6 v1 v9 v5
```

How I can sort **df** using **df2** but with v10 always in the last position?

My result should be:

```
df = v8 v3 v6 v4 v2 v7 v6 v1 v9 v5 v10
```

Comment: you can use `df[names(df2)]`

Comment: But I lost the Target column

Comment: If it is 'v10', then `df[c(names(df2), "v10")]`  It ensures that 'v10' is last